# Using BeautifulSoup to Match string in a html document and highlight it where ever it appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to match a string in a HTML document and highlight it particularly.
I have used BeautifulSoup along with html.parser.

What i have tried so far is using find_all() and passing the string to be matched but it doesnt help as it returns the whole text present in the element.

I want you to guide me how to target the particular string in the document and highlight it.

For Eg: Markup:

```
 <p>Lorem  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p> 
 <p>Lorem has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
```

After Highlighting: Markup:

```
 <p><mark>Lorem</mark> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p> 
 <p><mark>Lorem</mark> has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
```

Expected Output:

**Lorem** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**Lorem** has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it

If i could get a array of the strings i can replace it with the mark tag .

**GOT SO FAR with beautifulsoup** :

```
 import urllib.request
 import re
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://courseweb.stthomas.edu/mjodonnell/cojo258/resume/simple_code.html').read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')


 body = soup.find('body')

 results = body.find_all(text=re.compile(r'bastyr', re.I))

 print(results)
```

Comment: elaborate your "highlighting"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I edited the Question.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try something like this

```
soup = bs("<p>Lorem  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p> ",'lxml')

# This is the word we want to put a tag around
special_word = 'Lorem'
content_orig = soup.p.text
split_content_orig = content_orig.split(special_word)

soup.p.string = ''  
soup.p.insert(len(soup.p), split_content_orig[0])

for i_word in split_content_orig[1:]:
# We need to create a new tag in every loop, otherwise it moves the tag around. Probably has something to do with each tag having a unique id()
    new_tag = soup.new_tag('mark')
    new_tag.string = special_word
    soup.p.insert(len(soup.p), new_tag)
    soup.p.insert(len(soup.p), i_word)
```

I had a similar problem, and stated my question here:

[Replace text with bold version in Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326981/replace-text-with-bold-version-in-beautiful-soup)

Maybe somebody else will reply to it and find a better solution. But in the mean time you can use this I guess

Comment: Strange that your question was deleted.  Why was that?  Did you ever get any good answers?

Comment: @MatthewWalker No idea, I just noticed this as well. A Community bot removed it, maybe because of the inactivity on the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a more complex html, probably you don't want replace the text anywhere in the html. That could break links, images, styles and so.

You can replace only the instances of the text doing:

```
def highlight_html(html, re_highlighter):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.strings:
        highlighted = re_highlighter.sub(r"<mark>\1</mark>", tag)
        if highlighted != tag:
            highligted_soup = BeautifulSoup(highlighted, 'html.parser')
            tag.replace_with(highligted_soup)
    return str(soup)

# create your re rule as needed...
re_highlighter = re.compile(r"Lorem...", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
highlighted_html = highlight_html(html, re_highlight)
```